# SSIS excel formatting wont change from text field in destination editor **work around in place**

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have created an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2008 that take's a SQL select statement and populates a excel sheet, the excel sheet is duplicated from a template file with all the formatting and cells set up.

The issue I am having is that no matter what I do I can not change the excel destination formatting to anything other than general, it overwrites the source destination and puts decimal numbers a '1.50 always adding the ' to fields.

i have tried inserting a row as per some suggestions as people think this is where SSIS scans for formatting types. However the field always comes up as `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]` in the advance editor and always defaults back if i change them.

Please can someone help! Happy to provide any additional info if I've missed anything, I've seen some posts with the same issue, but none of the solutions seem to be working or i'm missing something else.

****Update****
Figured out the reason behind none of the recommended fixes working,  this was due to using a select statement in the excel destination instead of selecting the table.
[image]

This essentially wipes out any change if changing formatting.

So what I decided in the end was to create a data only sheet(which is hidden) using the basic table data access mode, then reference that in a front end sheet with all the formatting all ready in and using a `=value(C1)` formula to return just the value. Protected the cells to hide the formula's.

Comment: What is the output on the column from the SQL query, I imagine this is likely to the `Unicode`, have you tried changing this as well as the output?

Comment: See my suggestions in an answer below... and a question, related to step (3) below:  if you don't use the template, but generate a fresh Destination spreadsheet using the Data Flow's button... then, what format is given to the column in question?

Comment: Just throwing it out there: using IMEX in your connection string helps with datatypes when importing Excel data. perhaps it will also help when exporting data. Search on 'Excel IMEX' and you'll get a lot of hits.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Never knew about the IMEX switch, hasnt made any impact on this issue but is good to know going forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that, when I change a `Data Flow Task` in SSIS, that exports to (or imports from) Excel, I often have to "start over", or SSIS will somehow retain the some of the properties of the old `Data Flow Task`:  data types, column positions...  For me, that often means:

1) Deleting the Source and Destination objects within the Data Flow Task, **AND ALSO** deleting/recreating the *Connection Object* for the Excel spreadsheet.  I've done this enough times that I now save myself time by copy/pasting my Source and Destination names to-and-from a Notepad window, and I choose names that remind me of the objects they referred to (the table and file, respectively).

2) Remembering to rebuild the ARROW's metadata, too:  after you change and/or recreate the Source object, you have to remember to **DOUBLE-CLICK THE ARROW NEXT**, before re-creating the Destination.  That shows the arrow's metadata, but it also creates/updates the arrow's metadata.

3) When recreating the destination, DELETE THE SPREADSHEET from prior runs (or rename or move, etc.), and have SSIS recreate it.  (In your new destination object, there's a button to create that spreadsheet, using the metadata.)

If you still have problems after the above, take a look at your data types... make sure you've picked SQL datatypes that SSIS supports.

At the link below, about 2/3rds of the way down the page, you'll find a table **"Mapping of Integration Services Data Types to Database Data Types"**, with SSIS data types in the 1st column ("Data Type"), and your T-SQL equivalent data types in the 3rd column ("SQL Server (SqlClient)"):

[Integration Services Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)

Hope that helps...

Comment: @Doug-Ivison Thanks for the reply, even after doing the above the issue still happened, however I have figured out why its doing what it does. In the process in stead of selecting table is SSIS I am using a sql select (SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$b5:j5] ) so that data appears in cell B5. Its at this point the data type's fall over and can not be changed.

Only workaround I've managed to think of is to create two blank columns next to the one's I want and format them, putting a =Value(B6) to return the value of the auto populated cell!

Thanks for replying, up-vote and accept done as a good answer.

Comment: @Gavlaaa Interesting problem, and interesting idea for a solution.  Please consider leaving a comment (or adding an "update:" to the end of your question), when you see whether it is resolved or not.  Good luck.